# a%*%b = 1 but a%*%b==1 is FALSE, a and b have limit decimal places

Tags: r, numeric

```
info <- rep(NA,20)
for (j in 1:20) {
  info[j] <- pnorm(0.1*j-1,0,1/4.5)-pnorm(0.1*j-1-0.1,0,1/4.5)
}

info <- as.numeric(sprintf("%.5f",info))

initialsol <- as.vector(t(as.matrix(cbind(matrix(0.000001,20,10),as.matrix(info-0.000001*10)))))
```

In short, *initialsol* is a vector that sums up to 1 with limit decimal places.

```
rep(1,220)%*%initialsol
```

turns out to be 1. However,

```
rep(1,220)%*%initialsol==1
```

is FALSE. Why is that?

Comment: A simpler version, (rep(1,20)%*%rep(1/20,20))>1 is TRUE while (rep(1,10)%*%rep(1/10,10))>1 is FALSE.

Comment: That is mostly because of floating-point rounding error. Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal

Comment: Check out `print(rep(1,220)%*%initialsol, digits=20)` for example.

Comment: It's basic but I didn't know that. Thank you guys!